# invoke_ascmd on sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a local cube through an SSIS task. With earlier version of sql server I used `ascmd`. I could not find `ascmd` for sql server 2012, so I used `invoke-ascmd`. However when I use the -Server option to point to the local cube,  it errors out with the message:

> Warning WarningCode="-1055653884" Description="Errors in the met adata
>   manager. Either the database with the ID of '' does not exist
>   in the server with the ID of '\LocalCube', or the user does
>   not have permissions to access the object." Source="Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2012 Analysis Services"

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be happening only when I migrate projects from sql server 2008. Simply migrating the analysis server project, and changing the connection string values in datasource,building,deploying and recreating the xmla script does not seem to be enough. 
I need to actually go to the analysis server project delete the cube, data source etc. and recreate them and then recreate the xmla script.